# Shortcode with a foreach and arguments

Tags: loop, shortcode

I'm digging into shortcodes expert level

I made some searches and I really think I'm on the right path but I need your help because something is missing me (probably because I don't know very well how to code a condition).

So, on my website I have in a lot of pages a block with a HTML `<select>`, with these lists it's possible to open a file from my server.

The original HTML is like this:

```
<form name="example">
  <select name="download_files">
    <option value="">TITLE</option>
    <option value="https://example.com/file1.pdf">FILE 1</option>
    <option value="https://example.com/file2.pdf">FILE 2</option>
  </select>
  <a class="button">Download</a>
</form>
```

There are some items that I want to make it dynamic so I can write the shortcode and the function do the job, something like this `[download title="Configuration" files_title="File 1, File 2" files_name="file1.pdf, file2.pdf"]`

```
function download_files($atts){
    $att = shortcode_atts( array(
      'title' => 'Configuration',
      'files_title' => ['File 1',' File 2'],
      'files_name' => ['file1.pdf', 'file2.pdf']
    ), $atts );

  $output = '<form name="example">
              <span>' . $att['TITLE'] . '</span>
              <select name="download_files">';
                foreach ($files[0] as $file) {
                    $output .= '<option value="https://example.com/' . $att['files_name'] . '">' . $att['files_name'] . '</option>'
                }
  $output .= '</select><a class="button">Download</a></form>';

  return $output;
}

add_shortcode( 'form-render', 'download_files' );
```

I know something is not right but I can't figure out what… can you help me?

Comment: Why do you have `[0]` on your `$files` variable? And where does `$files` come from? It looks like it was pulled from thin air. You also can't pass an array into a shortcode, only strings. If I were you, it would make more sense to have a `[files]` shortcode, and put `[file]` shortcodes inside it, e.g. `[files title="title"][file url="..."]First file[/file][file url="..."]second file[/file][/files]`. Otherwise the reason your foreach doesn't work is because it's being used on a variable that does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```php
foreach ($files[0] as $file) {
```

**There is no `$files` variable, so there is nothing to loop through.**

You can't pull variables out of thin air and expect PHP to understand your intent. Computers are very literal, in the most extreme sense. They can't intuit what you meant, or want. This code should be generating lots of PHP notices and warnings in your error log file when it runs.

Fundamentally, you can't pass arrays/lists like this to shortcodes. Shortcode attributes are strings, text. Because of this, you cannot use an array as a default value, it doesn't make sense:

```php
      // this is not possible:
      'files_title' => ['File 1',' File 2'],
      'files_name' => ['file1.pdf', 'file2.pdf']
```

You can pass a comma separated list however, as your shortcode example demonstrates:

```php
      'files_title' => 'File 1, File 2',
      'files_name' => 'file1.pdf, file2.pdf'
```

Then use `explode` to get an array, e.g. `$file_titles = explode( ',', $att['files_title'];`, then do it again for `files_name`. At this point, you have a generic PHP problem rather than a WordPress problem. You would have to create a new array from those 2 arrays where each item is an array with a title and name key, e.g. `[ [ 'title'=>'File 1', 'name' => 'file1.pdf' ], [ 'title' => 'File 2' ... etc`.

This is the kind of thing you would do in the first year of a computer science degree, or in a general programming book, but anybody can do it if they understand the fundamental basics of the programming language, specifically loops and arrays,

Alternatively, use composition. Don't define your files in attributes, give them their own shortcodes:

```
[files title="title"]
[file url="..."]First file[/file]
[file url="..."]second file[/file]
[/files]
```

That way the `file` shortcode can be for just the `<option>` tag.

Fundamentally though, shortcodes are an old feature, you should consider replacing them with a block instead

Comment: Thank you! Your comments helped me to understand the way to go, I decided to use 2 shortcodes, one for the select and other for each option ;)

Comment: as a final note, `file` and `files` are very generic shortcode names, you will want to add a prefix to avoid clashes

Comment: These names are just examples, I added different names. Thank you